# Calculating density map of cycleways using fishnet in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vector-grid, road, density

How can I calculate density map of cycleways (line feature) which refers to net grid in ArcGIS?

Result by using function Line Density in ArcGIS for me is not satisyfing.

I created reference grid net by using Fish net. Now I would like to know how many m or km of cycleways occure in every grid to create density map. 
I enclose youtube link from QGIS program with result which I would like to achieve in ArcGIS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nb4-1ZRJbE

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this I would:

1. Intersect your cycleways and the fishnet
2. Use Summary Statistics to SUM the lengths of the intersected cycleways by fishnet polygon ID
3. Use Join Field to join the summed lengths back onto your fishnet using fishnet polygon ID as the join field

Comment: Everything works up until the 'Join field' step. I try to add the calculated table linking its column 'FID_Fishnet', to the 'OID' column of the Fishnet layer. The columns of the table are added to the fishnet layer, but all values are <null>. Do the names of the columns need to be identical?

Comment: @Treebeard The names don't need to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fishnet as reference surface
2. Intersection to get each line the Grid number
3. Dissolve refer to Grid number to sum up all `ShpLength` in each Grid number
4. From  grid feature, use join by attribute to join the `sum_Shp_Length` value back using the `Grid ID` or `Grid ObjID` or `Grid Name` as a reference