# Calculating route length per grid cell using fishnet

Tags: shapefile, vector-grid, length, density

I have a problem determining the length of the routes (boat) I've surveyed in order to calculate the survey effort. I added the GPS points of the boat and then used the points to line tool and added a field in the attribute table with the length of each route. 
Then I used the steps described by PolyGeo♦ here: [Calculating density map of cycleways using fishnet in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223865/calculating-density-map-of-cycleways-using-fishnet-in-arcgis-desktop/301834?noredirect=1#comment486181_301834)
but for some reason it doesn't work for me, I only get zeros and not the length per grid cell. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Actually, I just solved that problem myself - by adding a field to the attribute table of the intersected routes by fishnet polygon ID and caculated the geometry and now I have the length of the route per gridcel! :)

Comment: In that case, feel free to add the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it, this way people having the same question will find the answer more quickly.